# Create view with parameterized name and table name in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Hello I would like to create a parameter that will input to create an sql view

```
IF OBJECT_ID('view_rhscir2_CiMobTrack1', 'V') IS NOT NULL
    DROP VIEW view_rhscir2_CiMobTrack1
GO
create view view_rhscir2_CiMobTrack1 as
select * from [dbo].[Form_RHSCIR2_CIMobilityTracking_1]
GO
```

desired code:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('@SQLLView', 'V') IS NOT NULL
    DROP VIEW @SQLLView
GO
create view @SQLLView as
select * from [dbo].[@SourceTable]
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [dynamic sql](https://www.google.com/search?q=dynamic%20sql&oq=dynamic%20sql&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l2j69i59j0l2.1592j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

For example:

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(max) = '
IF OBJECT_ID('''+@SQLLView+''', ''V'') IS NOT NULL
    DROP VIEW '+@SQLLView+'

create view '+@SQLLView+' as
select * from [dbo].['+@SourceTable+']
'

EXECUTE (@sql);
```

There are many other considerations, that will find as you explore the link I posted.  For instance, you cannot use GO in a stored procedure, so I took that out, but since your desired code probably won't work without it, you'll need to figure that out (maybe two stored procedures).   Also it's best to use the QUOTENAME function in dynamic SQL instead of putting the square brackets in your string.

There are already a lot of articles about dynamic sql so I don't need to add any more detail here.   Frankly this is probably an XY problem, and there's probably a better way to do what you want than what you are trying to do, but this answer is treating your question as academic.